# Creating a firebase database duplicate

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a replica of my main database for the sake of testing. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

What I have tried is exporting the entire main-database into a bucket. Then I downloaded the `2022-10-24T16-etc.overall_export_metadata` file from that bucket and uploaded it to a bucket for test-database. However, when I try to import that file, I get an error

```
Google Cloud Storage file does not exist: /database-copy/database-copy.overall_export_metadata
```

I'm a little confused as to why its looking for `/database-copy/database-copy.overall_export_metadata` when the file im trying to upload looks more like `/database-copy/2022-10-24T16-etc.overall_export_metadata`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a document that explains how to do this,

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/move-data